# Authentication failed in curl request to list plans

Tags: git, curl, paypal

I am trying to list the billing plans in my PayPal

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans_list

this is the example in the developer.paypal.com about the request to list all the plans in my sandbox

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans?page_size=2&page=1&total_required=true \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"
```

The document says that I can use `Authorization: Basic <client_id>:<secret>`

so what I did is this:

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans?page_size=2&page=1&total_required=true \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Basic qwerty:zxcvbn"
```

I just replaced my client id and secret id in the example, and I got those from my account's sandbox here:

[image: m]

If I use that curl in my git bash

[image: git]

I get this error:

```
{ [244 bytes data]
100   244  100   244    0     0    177      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   177{"name":"AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE","message":"Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header.","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#error","rel":"information_link"}]}
```

How come I still get an "Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials" even as I added my correct sandbox ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The oAuth URI is https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token

So your call should be something like

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
   -H "Accept: application/json" \
   -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
   -u "client_id:secret" \
   -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

More info on https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/get-an-access-token-curl/